# Is a "Front-end Architect" role relavent when developing a modern webapp?

Tags: javascript, html, css, web-applications, architecture

Should/does this role get recognized by the software development community?

In my mind, someone with this position would make high-level decisions on coding standards, design choices, tools and frameworks for HTML, CSS and JavaScript.

Maybe there's a better name for it? I'm trying to better state my career goals, and I need some perspective. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes.  sufficiently complex RIAs are almost completely independent applications, and thus they need their own experts/teams.

If you have developers who are familiar with both server and client side development, then they might be able to participate in the development of both tiers of the application.  However, a complex RIA can easily be as or more complex than the server, so if the app is big enough you probably need dedicated resources for both the server and the RIA, as well as possibly the DB.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, the role of a [software architect](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_architect) includes design choices, coding standards, etc. so a front-end architect would naturally make decisions regarding front-end web technologies like HTML/CSS/JavaScript, etc.